# A question from Kunen's book: chapter VII (H9), about diamond principle

Tags: set-theory, forcing, infinitary-combinatorics

> Assume $(\mathbb{P}$ is c.c.c.$)^M$ and $\Diamond$ holds in $M[G]$. Show that $\Diamond$ holds in $M$.
>
> Hint: It is sufficient to verify $\Diamond^-$ in $M$.

Should I try to create a $\Diamond$ sequence or $\Diamond^{-}$ sequence? Should I work with nice names?

Comment: If $\langle \dot A_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ is the sequence of names for a diamond sequence, use the fact that $\Bbb P$ is c.c.c. to create a $\lozenge$ sequence in $M$.

Comment: Should I try to create a $\Diamond$ sequence or $\Diamond^{-}$ sequence ? Should I work with nice names ?

Comment: I honestly don't recall all the different diamond sequences. So I can't be of much more help.

Comment: Recall that $\Diamond^-$ is equivalent to $\Diamond$, so if you are able to manage a $\Diamond^-$-sequence you are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\langle A_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ is a $\diamondsuit$-sequence in $M[G]$, pick $p\in G$  such that $$p\Vdash \langle \dot A_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\rangle\text{ is a }\diamondsuit\text{-sequence}.$$ Now consider, in $M$, for each $\alpha<\omega_1$, $\mathcal A_\alpha:=\{A\subseteq\alpha:$for some $q\leq p, q\Vdash \check A=\dot A_\alpha\},$ then each $\mathcal A_\alpha$ is countable.

Comment: Why is every $A \in \mathcal{A}_{\alpha}$ fulfills $A \subset \alpha$ ? We have a $p$ such that $p \Vdash \check{A} = \dot{A}_\alpha$. If $p \in G$ it's OK. But what if $p \notin G$ ?

Comment: But why $\dot{A}_{\alpha}^H \subset \alpha$ ?